# QTimer in QThread fires signal, but GUI thread isnt updated

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I have two QMainWindows, one of which I want to hide for some time, while its loading the stuff it needs, and then show the other one. While the other one is shown, it should periodically (through a QTimer) change the image it is showing. I manage to do most of it, but even though the slot to update the image is being called, the second QMainWindow isnt updated.

This is the loading window class header:

```
#ifndef LOADINGWINDOW_H
#define LOADINGWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QImage>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class LoadingWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit LoadingWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void startLoading();
    void stopLoading();

private slots:
    void loadingTimerExpired();

private:
    QLabel *m_loadingLabel;
    QVector<QPixmap> m_loadingPixmaps;
    QTimer *m_loadingTimer;
    int m_currentLoadingImage;
    QThread* m_loadingThread;

};

#endif // LOADINGWINDOW_H
```

And the .cpp file:

```
#include "loadingwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QSettings>
#include <QFile>
#include <QThread>

LoadingWindow::LoadingWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{

    QSettings appSettings("app.ini",  QSettings::IniFormat);
    QString appPath = appSettings.value("appSettings/appPath").toString();
    QFile file(appPath + "/style.qss");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QTextStream ts(&file);
    qApp->setStyleSheet(ts.readAll());


    m_loadingLabel = new QLabel();
    m_loadingPixmaps = QVector<QPixmap>(N_IMAGES);
    for (int i=0; i<m_loadingImgs.size(); i++)
    {
        m_loadingImgs[i] = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage(":/loadingImg" +
                                  QString::number(i) + ".png").scaled(QSize(800,500), Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    }

    m_currentLoadingImage = 0;

    m_currentLoadingImage++;
    m_loadingLabel->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
    m_loadingLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    m_loadingLabel->setPixmap(m_loadingPixmaps[0]);
    m_loadingLabel->adjustSize();
    m_loadingLabel->move(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center() - m_loadingLabel->rect().center());

    this->setCentralWidget(m_loadingLabel);
    this->adjustSize();
    this->move(QApplication::desktop()->screen()->rect().center() - m_loadingLabel->rect().center());


    m_loadingTimer = new QTimer();
    m_loadingTimer->setInterval(70);
    m_loadingThread = new QThread(this);
    m_loadingTimer->moveToThread(m_loadingThread);
    QObject::connect(m_loadingTimer,
                     SIGNAL(timeout()),
                     this,
                     SLOT(loadingTimerExpired())
                     , Qt::DirectConnection);

    QObject::connect(m_loadingThread,
                     SIGNAL(started()),
                     m_loadingTimer,
                     SLOT(start()));

    QObject::connect(m_loadingThread,
                     SIGNAL(finished()),
                     m_loadingTimer,
                     SLOT(stop()));

}

void LoadingWindow::startLoading()
{
    m_loadingThread->start();
    this->show();
    QApplication::processEvents();
}

void LoadingWindow::stopLoading()
{
    this->hide();
    m_loadingThread->exit();
}


void LoadingWindow::loadingTimerExpired()
{


    m_loadingLabel->setPixmap(m_loadingPixmaps[m_currentLoadingImage]);
    m_loadingLabel->update();
    QApplication::processEvents();

    m_currentLoadingImage++;
    if (m_currentLoadingImage == m_loadingPixmaps.size())
        m_currentLoadingImage=0;
}
```

From my first qmainwindow I just fire the loading window by calling startLoading() (and setting the other mainwindow.setVisible(false))

The thing is that the loading window is shown, but it doesnt change its images. I know that the loadingTimerExpired() is being fired each 70ms, as expected, because Ive printed some debug message from there. My guess then is that the

```
m_loadingLabel->update();
QApplication::processEvents();
```

sentences are not working as I expect them to, and that the GUI thread is blocked somehow. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Qt::DirectConnection` when firing signals across threads in this case as you are doing GUI stuff in the slot. `Qt::DirectConnection:` [`The slot is invoked immediately when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the signalling thread`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: If I dont use the Qt::DirectConnection I saw that the slot loadingTimerExpired() isnt fired until the first mainwindow has finished doing its calculations.

Comment: Then why aren't these calculations done in a different thread?

Comment: Ok... is there any way to use queued connection or auto and give it a priority so high that it will be executed instantly?

Comment: Well, because it meant rewritting a lot of codejust to add the loading screen... But if its the only way to go I might have to consider it

Comment: I'm not sure why do you even move the `QTimer` object to a new thread. You should move the heavy calculations in the new thread.

Comment: Because if I didnt do that the qtimer lived in the gui thread and wouldnt even fire

Comment: Of course not. It needs a free event loop to do that. The main event loop should never be blocked for a long period of time. It causes the GUI to freeze among other things.